# Center div elements like text

Tags: html, css

I looked around but couldn't find something that works. I'd like to somehow center `div` elements that have `class="box"`. Here is an example of how I would like it to be:

[image]

Can someone tell me how I would go about doing this? I have tried something that obviously wouldn't work but here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 36);
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 56);
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(20, 20, 26);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 95vh;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.box {
  margin: auto 0;
  left: 25;
  right: 25;
  top: 25;
  bottom: 25;
  height: 160px;
  width: 140px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(20, 20, 26);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 76);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

P.S. Don't just post code, please. I want to learn so please explain how it all works

Comment: You got your margin the wrong way round should be 0 auto not auto 0 :-)

Comment: @AndrewBone That almost fixes it. I tried this but if you look at my example I want it to be like text. A few in a line. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your `#main` parent div `display: flex` & `justify-content: space-between`. And then accordingly give your `width` to box. Like:

```
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width: 30%;
}

.box:nth-child(4),
.box:nth-child(5) {
  width: 45%;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full view for better understanding*):

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 36);
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 56);
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(20, 20, 26);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 95vh;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.box {
  margin: 10px 0;
  left: 25;
  right: 25;
  top: 25;
  bottom: 25;
  height: 160px;
  width: 30%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(20, 20, 26);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 76);
}

.box:nth-child(4),
.box:nth-child(5) {
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: One last thing: How do you move it from all 4 sides? Other than that, does the trick!

Comment: @NedasBolevičius I used `justify-content: space-between` which is responsible for creating gaps in between each `.box` div. Hope you got the answer.

Comment: I was talking about how do you move the boxes from the outer box's sides?

Comment: @NedasBolevičius If I got you right you are asking about the 4th & 5th `box` div. I've used `nth-child` for this. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution, but it definitely fits me. Thank you! Works fine

Comment: Its my pleasure @NedasBolevičius

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox, you can `justify-content: space-around;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` this means evenly space elements along a line and if the line has too much on it start a new line.

Here is some more resources and example about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

I've made a simple example below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wall {
  background: #bed6e2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.brick {
  width: calc(100%/9);
  height: 65px;
  background: #ab837b;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
.brick.wide {
  width: calc((100% / 9) * 3);
}
```

```html
<div id="wall">
  <div class="brick wide"></div>
  <div class="brick wide"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
  <div class="brick wide"></div>
  <div class="brick wide"></div>
  <div class="brick wide"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
  <div class="brick wide"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is great but it has its downsides, I prefer to stick to using float.

There a 2 new classes, box1 and box2 which have styles specific to the size of the box (you might want to look at using a [grid system](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/))

There is also a [`.clearfix`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) class which is clears your floats.

I took the liberty of tidying various bits of your css that were not needed. If you want to know more let me know.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 36);
}
#main {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 56);
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border:3px solid rgb(20, 20, 26);  
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.box {
  margin: 25px 0;
  height: 75px;
  border: 3px solid  rgb(20, 20, 26);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 76);
  float: left;
}
.box1 {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.box1:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.box2 {
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.box2:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main" class="clearfix">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works fine, but I prefer the other solution. Thank you! Helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem, as long as you got it working. Just be aware of the browser support. specifically for Internet Explorer. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements have the property `display: block` by default. Block-level elements automatically begin on a new line, but adding the attribute `display: inline-block` on `.box` will let the elements exist on the same line. Applying `text-align: center` to the container holding your `.box`es (which is `#main`) will center the inline-blocks inside.

Alternatively, you could apply `display: flex` to `#main` which will automatically manage the position of all elements inside (by default, in a row). You can customize this extensively without needing additional styles on `.box`. Read more here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Well, almost correct. But the problem is that 1-no space between the divs, 2- text is also centered.

Comment: @NedasBolevičius Easily fixed! Add space between the divs with `margin: 0 8px;` on `.box` (adjust 8px as needed), and uncenter the text with `text-align: left` on `.box` (but keep it on `#main`).

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated answer

Try to use `display: flex` to parent container and if you want wrap content to second line then use `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 36);
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 56);
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(20, 20, 26);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 95vh;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container_second .box {
  width: 180px;
}

.box {
  margin: auto 0;
  left: 25;
  right: 25;
  top: 25;
  bottom: 25;
  height: 160px;
  width: 140px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(20, 20, 26);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 76);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container container_second">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
```

For complete reference on flex - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: That almost fixes it. I tried this but if you look at my example I want it to be like text. A few in a line. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: @NedasBolevičius in that case you need to wrap them to individual `container`.

Comment: @NedasBolevičius See updated answer, hope this will help you in some way :)

Comment: Yep, that pretty much does the trick. But how do I move it from the left, right, bottom and top? I don't want it to be touching. Also could you explain the code for me? The P.S. says why.

Comment: @NedasBolevičius this is `dispaly: flex` for complete understanding look here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @NedasBolevičius If you want it to move from left, right, bottom or top then you can always use `margin` e.g. `margin: top right bottom left;` something like `margin: 10 15 5 20`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 0 margin in the left_right (the margin style of .box) try using 40%

use:

```
.box {
  margin: auto 40%;
```

instead of:

```
.box {
  margin: auto 0;
```

The percentage will keep 40% of the total width of the margin on each side. It is important to note though that if you change the width of the box class you will need to adjust the margins also.